# Can't grab html element from with node JS + cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, web-scraping, cheerio

I wrote this code to grab some element from VK page. But it returns `null`. Can you help me, if I need to grab name and profile picture? Why can't I use this?

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://vk.com/durov', (err, res, html) => {
  if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    const nameElement = $('.page_block');

    console.log(nameElement.html());
  }
});
```

Comment: Since node.js is server side you wont be able to access the DOM at all here. You can get it in the client side js and pass it as a post body to the node layer and perform functions.

Comment: I saw a lot of working examples, for example - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoziivfAAjE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this site checks for some user-agent templates. For instance the following works :

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request({
    url: 'https://vk.com/durov',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1'
    }
}, (err, res, html) => {
    if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        console.log($('.page_block').html());
    }
});
```

Comment: also, if you (nptsh) log `$('.page_block').html()` instead of `$('. page_block').html()` you will find the html you were looking for...